# How to get the current state array after re-ordering the columns of Angular datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatables

This is an interesting case, Im achieving to get the current state of array of the columns when I use pure JS + jQuery but when trying to achieve the same thing in Angular 12 this won't work!
Im reading the docs of Angular datatables also datatables.net but this won't work on the project!

Here is the code im trying to set up in Angular:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
declare var $:JQueryStatic;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-mandant',
  templateUrl: './mandant.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mandant.component.scss']
})
export class MandantComponent implements OnInit {

  dtOptions = {};
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.dtOptions = {
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      bLengthChange: true,
      searching: false,
      table: "#dttable",
      info: true,
      buttons: [
        'colvis',
        'copy',
        'print',
        'excel',
        {
          text: 'Some button',
          key: '1',
          action: function (e: any, dt: any, node: any, config: any) {
            alert('Button activated');
          }
        }
      ],
      colReorder: {
        enable: true,
        order: [1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
      }
    };

    this.dtOptions.on('column-reorder.dt', function (e, settings, details) {
      console.log("You just reordered the cols, here is your current state: ", this.dtOptions.order());
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    
  }
}
```

The achievement for me is this piece of code, if this code returns the current state of the array after each change on the columns, my concern is done:

```
this.dtOptions.on('column-reorder.dt', function (e, settings, details) {
      console.log("You just reordered the cols, here is your current state: ", this.dtOptions.order());
    });
```

Comment: When you think dtoptions.on methoa gets call?

Comment: The issue is that this method never gets called! I expect this to be called right after you release the column.

Comment: I think I have found out a solutions for this problem.

Comment: @GRD Im all eyes :)

Comment: Hey @GRD sorry I found the solution, but ofc if I can help you, I will do it :). Tell me your case!?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after few days, I was trying to load everything on `ngViewInit();` but actualy I had to do that on `ngAfterViewInit();`:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mandant',
  templateUrl: './mandant.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mandant.component.scss']
})
export class MandantComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('dataTable', { static: false }) table: any;
  dtOptions: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    var cols: any = localStorage.getItem("mandanten") === null ? null : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mandanten") || "[]");
    this.dtOptions = {
      dom: "Bfrtip",
      "buttons": [
        "colvis",
        "copy",
        "excel"
      ],
      "colReorder": {
        "enable": true,
        "realtime": false,
        "order": cols,
      }
    };

    var table: any = $(this.table.nativeElement).DataTable(this.dtOptions);

    table.on("column-reorder", function () {
      localStorage.setItem("mandanten", JSON.stringify(table.colReorder.order()));
    });

    table.on( 'buttons-action', function ( e: any, buttonApi: any, dataTable: any, node: any, config: any ) {
      console.log(buttonApi.columns());
  } );
  };

  ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```